# use pipe in ngrx selector

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I want a memoized selector which includes a rxjs transformation in its projector function. Tried like that to get arrays of `FunctionProps` per group of `FunctionProps.Category` of an `FunctionProps[]` array which is selected by memoized selector `selectFunctionProperties`:

```
   export const selectGroupedFunctionProperties = createSelector(
    selectFunctionProperties,
    (f) => from(f).pipe(
        groupBy((v: FunctionProps) => v.Category),
        mergeMap(group => group.pipe(toArray())),
        toArray()
    )
);
```

As you can see I used a 'from' to get a pipeable observable from the source FunctionProps[] array. This of course is not a good idea, because the selectGroupedFunctionProperties selector now is an observable of observable in the consuming component.

Is there an approach to have the pipe in a memoized selector instead of using the pipe in the component `this.store.select(selectFunctionProperties).pipe(...)` ?

I want to be able to combine selectors and keep rxjs code out of components.

Otherwise is it a valid pattern to use a pipe in a selector
(so I cannot avoid implementing groupBy for array with type script as *pure function* inside the selector)?

**EDIT**
I changed the selector using the pipe operator directly:

```
export const selectGroupedFunctionProperties = pipe(
    select(selectFunctionProperties),
    concatMap(functions => functions),
    groupBy(v => v.Category),
    mergeMap(group => group.pipe(toArray())),
    toArray(),
);
```

In the component I receive the Functionprops[][] array with a pipe instead of the select:

```
groupedFunctions$ = this.store.pipe(selectGroupedFunctionProperties);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the option to export a pipe by itself (without createSelector):

```
export const selectGroupedFunctionProperties = pipe(
  select(selectFunctionProperties),
  groupBy((v: FunctionProps) => v.Category),
  mergeMap(group => group.pipe(toArray()))
  // I'm not quite sure, but I don't think you need the 'toArray'-operator
);
```

Have a look at the docs too for this: https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors#breaking-down-the-basics

Comment: Thank you Gunnar, somehow I've always read around the "advanced" section of the ngrx docs. I try it like that.

Comment: Need some more help with that, the rxjs statement with groupBy is not correct (see EDIT)

Comment: Got it, had to use pipe instead of select in the component.